# Is there a way to search through a dict and have it return all the PK containing the search variables

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I have looked all over the place and I have not been able to find a good way to do what I am wanting to do... The goal is to search through a dictionary array of employees, searching the key value called "Active" it is a True/False value, The way I have the employee dict is the following:

```
Employee{Empl_Num{"Fname":"John", "LName":"Smith", "Phone":"555-555-5555", "Active":True, "isManager":False}}
```

How I did the search by iterating through the dict and copy Items from the Employee dict to a Inactive Employee dict: The following is my code::

```
def Remove_Empl(self):
  #flips is active switch to inactive.#
  global Employee, EmplNum
  self.Prnt_Empl_Lst()
  Termed=int(raw_input("Please enter the employee number of the employee being termed: "))
  isValid=self.ValidateEmpl(Termed) #ensure a number entered exists
  if isValid==True: # is a valid employee number
     Employee[Termed]["Active"]=False #set active status == False
     self.get_Inact_Empl() #iterates through entire list of employee and checks active status
  else:
     print "No such employee exists, please check the employee list and try again."
  AdminMenu()



def get_Inact_Empl(self):
      global Employee, EmplInactive
      for InvlEmpl in Employee.keys(): #every employee number is searched...
         if Employee[InvlEmpl]["Active"]==False and EmplInactive.has_key(InvlEmpl): #if they are not active, but in array already should skip
            pass
         elif Employee[InvlEmpl]["Active"]==False and EmplInactive.has_key(InvlEmpl)==False:#if they are not active, but nit in array, add to array 
            EmplInactive[InvlEmpl]=Employee[InvlEmpl]
      for Empl in EmplInactive.keys(): ##Prints values in a neat list
         print str(Empl) +": ",
         for Empl1 in EmplInactive[Empl].keys():
            print EmplInactive[Empl][Empl1],
         print ""
```

The Wonderful fact is that the above code works... but just now when I go to add an employee that was termed from the company using the following:

```
def Add_Empl(self):
  global EmplNum, Employee,EmplInactive
  FirstName=raw_input("Please enter employees first name: ")
  LastName=raw_input("Please enter employees last name: ")
  Phone=raw_input("Please enter employees phone number: ")

  for IE_Key in EmplInactive.keys():
     if EmplInactive[IE_Key]["FirstName"]==FirstName and EmplInactive[IE_Key]["LastName"]==LastName and EmplInactive[IE_Key]["Phone"]==Phone:
        del EmplInactive[IE_Key]
        Employee[IE_Key]["Active"]=True
        break

  ##if there is no value then create a new entry##
  EmplNum+=1      
  Employee[EmplNum]={"FirstName":FirstName,"LastName":LastName,"Phone":Phone, "Active":True, "isManager":False} ## read following block comment on this##

  AdminMenu()
  '''
  Pretty much most is self explanitory, employee name, and phone, may add address here too... Important parts are the last three, Logged in#not yet added#
  Active meaning that the employee is a member of the corporation and not been termed either voluntary or involuntary. isManager is the designation that
  attaches employee to managers que, as a manager additional options become avail if logged in... employee and manager staff had seperate log ins and may
  proocess transactions as employee or as manager depending on log in status. Removal of employees can be done by manager level staff, However only marks
  Active status false. can be reactivated later date if needs be. DEFAULTS: Active=TRUE IsManager=FALSE LoggedIn=FALSE*when applied
  '''
```

It does what it is supposed to but it generates a new employee thus a copy, a new number and space in the dictionary... :( I have tried to put the section if there is no value in the inactive array add user , it either creates a new employee for each inactive user not matching the keys searched for, Or it only creates one entry additional... but it still is creating too many extra entries...

Please help... :'(

Jesse Fender

Comment: I did the following: `def get_Inact_Empl(self):
      global Employee, EmplInactive
      for InvlEmpl in Employee.keys(): 
         if Employee[InvlEmpl]["Active"]==False and EmplInactive.has_key(InvlEmpl): 
            pass
         elif Employee[InvlEmpl]["Active"]==False and EmplInactive.has_key(InvlEmpl)==False:
            EmplInactive[InvlEmpl]=Employee[InvlEmpl]
      for Empl in EmplInactive.keys():
         print str(Empl) +": ",
         for Empl1 in EmplInactive[Empl].keys():
            print EmplInactive[Empl][Empl1],
         print ""`

Comment: this is the code to mark employee inactive: `def Remove_Empl(self):
      global Employee, EmplNum
      self.Prnt_Empl_Lst()
      Termed=int(raw_input("Please enter the employee number of the employee being termed: "))
      isValid=self.ValidateEmpl(Termed)
      if isValid==True: # is a valid employee number
         Employee[Termed]["Active"]=False
         self.get_Inact_Empl()
      else:
         print "No such employee exists, please check the employee list and try again."
      AdminMenu()`